# Use conditional to check that the current user is the author of the post

Tags: conditionals, author

How can I check that the current user is the author of the post? Something like this?...

```
{if author_id="CURRENT_USER"}{/if}
```

*(My setup is basically an entries loop, with a snippet inside of that containing all the variables to display each entry. Within that I want to conditionally show an embedded include which holds a delete form. So basically I only want to show the delete form for entries which are authored by the current user. Got it all working okay, just need the conditional now.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare to the [`member_id`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#member-id) global variable:

```
{if member_id == author_id}
```

Or use the [alternative syntax](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#alternative-syntax):

```
{if logged_in_member_id == author_id}
```

Just remember that global variables are parsed at the end of parsing stages. So, the content inside the conditional will bee removed only after all previous [parsing stages](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html). Because of that, you **should not** put an embed inside it.

Comment: Ah nice thank you. What about if I was to put it inside the embed, setting variables e.g. `{embed:member_id}` and `{embed:author_id}` ?

Comment: The problem remains. The point is that you should avoid to parse a complete template to be removed. Try to keep everything inside the snippet.